# Ubuntu 18.04 quit booting. . *ERROR* DC failed to blank crtcl (screen photo)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 18.04, fsck

Dec 11: new summary. Ubu18.04lts laptop won't boot.
Tried again today viz::

EDITS FOR FLOW. Edit for more info.
- today I started again and pressed SHIFT  to get I to GRUB (grub2 iir) and got this

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfA1D.jpg

So I must learn fsck it seems.

---

**Original post follows:**

When I restart my PC, i get [this screen](https://askubuntu.com/review/first-posts/898397)
Situation:
1. Goes to grub.
2. See words (first few lines of that image)
3. Quickly flashes to Ubuntu splash screen
4. Then I get that image.

Bios settings have not changed.
I tried this and that but no success.
It will boot from a live USB.
    A. will read both Ubuntu and Windows partitions
    B. At first Cannot write to Ubuntu partition.
    C. Backed up onto win10 partition using GUI (mate).
    D. Then found it had done a move (mv) not a copy - from one partition to another.  So I carefully copied and restored those things on the extra volume aka the Ubuntu partition. At first it refused to copy a directory only files, then changed after I had done it manually a few times. (How can this be?)

If I knew more I would tell you. Doing this on a phone so forgive the awkwardness or typos.
The computer is an HP Probook 455 GET, vintage 2016.
AMD, hard drive, Radeon. Factoid: It won't work with 16.04.

> Separate issue: (posted just in case of knowledge at Reddit)  My Windows 10 partition sees 16 to 20 MORE WiFi networks than Ubuntu does. That makes me mad.. Ubuntu sees mine plus only 1 more while Windows sees 16TI 20.
>   HP does not offer a Linux driver for it on their site.

Thanks for all help. Free-node was stumped.

EDITS FOR FLOW. Edit for more info.
- today I started again and pressed SHIFT  to get I to GRUB (grub2 iir) and got this

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfA1D.jpg

So I must learn fsck +

Comment: Wifi is a separate issue, I think you'll likely get a tip from an admin about that. Might want to focus on it when you can get details from a system you can actually boot in to

Comment: Can't help notice that the message explicitly tells you to fsck yourself :) fsck is just a filesystem checker. In that case You must boot from a live disk/USB to run it though.

Answer (score 0):

Holler;

The solution to your problem may lie in changing the following in your kernel boot line:

amdgpu.dc=0

You can find a detailed description of how to do this temporarily here:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters